# Java 7 Concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-7

I would like implement Java concurrency API in such a way that at a time there will be max 4 parallel threads will be running. But I should be able add request to the pool and when data/ request is available it will process or maintain a queue. Processing logic will implement FIFO for peeking the request from pool/queue.

e.g. I have 5 requests r1 ... r5. Initial pool will have 5 request but it will process r1 to r3, rest will be in waiting state. After some time I can add 3 more request r6 ... r8. If 1 request is still running then r6 and r7 will star executing and r8 will be in waiting state.

Could you you please tell me How to achieve this using JDK 7 concurrency API.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: Check out `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`

Comment: FixedThreadPool will give me fixed parallel execution but can I add request to the pool for processing after executor.submit() method? Also at some point of time pool is blank and if I add request it should start process automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Implement the request consumers as Runnable. Let them to read the requests from FIFO queue such as ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

2/ Use java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool() to start wanted number of request consumers.

3/ The side which maintains the pool writes the requests into the FIFO queue.

That's all.

Comment: Thanks. Will implement this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed thread pools were created for. They will handle the queue for you. You can create one with [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)), or by directly creating a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). When each request comes in, create a new `Runnable` task, whose `run()` method processes the request. Add this task to your executor with `execute()` or `submit()`. The thread pool will work through calling all your tasks, and you can add new tasks at any time (as long as you have not yet called `shutdown()` on your executor.)